# Getting the view working in an App with no XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been trying to get a basic app working that doesnt use an XIB. It simply should load and draw a button.

At the moment the screen just appears white with apparently nothing on it.

In my delegate I pass across to my viewController Class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{  
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; 
return YES;
}
```

In my viewController class I implement loadview and viewDidLoad. Not sure if loadView is getting called. There is no XIB in this project.

```
-(void)viewDidload 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 UIButton *singlePlayerButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] 
retain];
singlePlayerButton.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 30.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[singlePlayerButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
singlePlayerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[singlePlayerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

[singlePlayerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:singlePlayerButton]; 
}

-(void)loadView 
{
NSLog(@"loadView");
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] 
applicationFrame]];
self.view = view;
[view release];
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

I though this would be really quiet simple but after 2hrs of hitting my head against the wall nothing has changed.

Thanks -Code

Comment: Have you set breakpoints and run in debug mode so that you can see if the methods are being called as you expect?

Comment: None of my methods in viewController are getting called.

Comment: Adding in viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init]; makes my loadview method get called. But no call of ViewDidLoad method. Screen is still blank.

Comment: Adding the button code into loadview gets the button to appear. It seems that that is the key to the whole problem.

Comment: Also, where are you creating your UIWindow instance?  You're adding views to it, but I don't see it being initialized anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewDidload` method has a case typo. It should be `viewDidLoad` (capital L).

Answer (score 0):

Stupid suggestion perhaps, but where in the app delegate are you instantiating viewController?

Comment: Hi Rengers, I wasnt until a few minutes ago. That was apart of my problem. Thanks for you input.